# Coworker might have entered with fake resume

Tags: resume, management, ethics, unprofessional-behavior, online-presence

A coworker has no online resume or LinkedIn. I also don't see them on Facebook, which is okay. I suspect that this person might have faked his resume, because he says he has many years of experience, but asks rather basic questions.

This person is not fit for the job. We have to do the heavy lifting for him.
In the case of this coworker, the chances are high that he has actually padded his resume with 4-6 years of fake experience.

How do I bring my concern in front of management ?

Comment: I've cut quite a lot out of this question as you're supposed to be asking a question here, not giving part of the answer. Strategies on verifying a coworker's resume are also likely outside SE's scope as that could fall under doxing.

Comment: Well no, actually. The issue here is that you're calling out a specific company which we don't normally allow in questions here. I take it your coworker was hired via the company mentioned in that article or is somehow related to it? If you edit this to something like "He was hired via a company that's been caught faking resumes" and remove the link then that would probably be fine. You don't need to prove anything here.

Comment: Anyhow, does this actually affect you? Standard advice in this situation is to [do nothing](http://www.askamanager.org/2008/09/should-i-tell-on-coworker-who-might.html) as it's [none of your business](http://www.askamanager.org/2012/12/i-think-my-new-manager-falsified-her-credentials.html).

Comment: This person is not fit for the job. We have to do the heavy lifting for him. Would you be okay with working with such a person ? Probably not. I hope you'll understand where I am coming from. Btw, the -1 was uncalled for.

Comment: Lilienthal - Moreover, you quoted some blog posts. Those are the opinions of one person. I would also like the opinions of other people on this forum, especially those who work in the software development industry.

Comment: The downvote isn't mine, though I'm tempted to as you seem overly attached to linking those articles which only seem to complicate what is actually a simple question. Your actual reasons for concern is that your coworker isn't pulling his weight and increasing the workload of you and your colleagues. Put *that* in your question and drop the links and I think your question will be much better received.

Comment: Those links are what I would base my answer on. The author of that blog probably has more experience with workplace matters than you and me combined and is someone with a fairly authoritative opinion on questions like this. Do note that this *isn't* a forum though, but a Q&A site.

Comment: What does the lack of LinkedIn and Facebook accounts have to do with your issue? I would suggest you remove those as well. Also, your links don't prove anything, *and* it is [not ok to name and shame](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/4109/3192).

Comment: [Related question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/17106/9549)

Comment: Not everyone uses LinkedIn and Facebook. Or he may have used them before but since deleted them, or he uses some other Web sites for social media, etc. etc. It almost sounds like you just searched around the Web and, based on a lack of online presence, somehow concluded the man faked his CV based on that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> How do I bring my concern in front of management ?

If you are convinced that your coworker has faked a resume, you could go to your boss with your accusation.

However, it appears that the only "evidence" you have is that your coworker claims many years of experience but asks rather basic questions. By itself, that proves nothing.

Accusing someone of something as unprofessional as this shouldn't be taken lightly. You are putting your own reputation in jeopardy here. What if you are wrong?

Have you see this person's resume? Did you interview him? Do you actually know what this person claimed during the interview? Did you check his references? Do you realize that your inability to find an online resume, LinkedIn account, or Facebook account means absolutely nothing?

Think this over very carefully before you do anything. If you still decide you are right, and still decide you should rat out your coworker, then just approach your boss with your feelings. Be prepared for your boss to disapprove of your actions - in my experience bosses don't like to see this sort of thing happen on their team.

If it were me, I'd be solely concerned about if the person is capable of doing the job or not, and dealing with that. What your coworker did or didn't do regarding his resume isn't your business, nor is it your problem. And I wouldn't ever accuse someone of anything unless I was absolutely sure.

Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Your questions are valid. I had mentioned that no online presence does not really mean anything. But, the mods removed all that. I found it strange that a person with 6 years of experience in web ui testing with selenium does not know the difference between explicit & implicit wait. This & the resume fraud incidents raised a red flag. Sure, I could tell management that its hard to work with him & let them take care of it. But, assuming (actually sure) that he had faked his resume, the bigger issue is with our hiring process. If we don't fix this, then it could lead to bigger problems. Thanks.

Comment: @Truthseekers Even  if he didn't lie on his resume (it _is_ possible to have experience as time in sevice, but still not have basics) you still have to review your hiring if someone so unqualified got through

Comment: @HorusKol - Lets forget the guy in my office. Maybe he is ok. Here is an example of faking resumes - http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/34149/different-resumes-versions-on-the-web-one-is-fake

Comment: @Truthseekers - actually, let's not forget about your question: I'm not saying CV fraud doesn't exist - but proving it in any particular case is difficult, pointing that finger will impact your reputation, and you will have a better chance if you stick to his apparent (in)competence